# java get even or odd number

Tags: java

I have a assignment for school: I need to get even or odd numbers and I made something to work for numbers that are above zero, but I need to find out how a negative number is even or odd.

```
String[] evenodd = {" number is even", " number is odd"};
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    int x = i;
    while (x > 1) x = x - 2;
    System.out.println(i + evenodd[x]);
}
```

Comment: Can't you use `%` operator? Or `&` operator?

Comment: The `%` operator denotes the `modulo` operator. It would make your life easier in this case, I'd recommend you look it up ;).

Comment: `(i%2 == 0)` if `i` is even. `(i&1 == 0)` if `i` is even.

Comment: @Eran `((i&1) == 0)` only works on two's compliment though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply use module % operator

```
String[] evenodd = {" number is even", " number is odd"};
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
int x;

if(i%2==0){
 x=0;/*pass 0 to print even number */
}else{
 x=1;/*pass 1 to print odd number*/
}
System.out.println(i + evenodd[x]);
}
```

Comment: Bro if condition slow down the processing. we can increment the variable i +2 and shows it.

Answer (score 1):

***Even*** and ***Odd*** numbers:

```
String[] evenodd = {" number is even", " number is odd"};
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i + evenodd[i % 2]);
}
```

**OR**

```
String[] evenodd = {" number is even", " number is odd"};
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if(i % 2 == 0)
         System.out.println(i + evenodd[i % 2]);
    else
         System.out.println(i + evenodd[i % 2]);
}
```

For **negative numbers** is even or odd?:

```
String[] evenodd = {" number is even", " number is odd"};
for(int i = 0; i > -100; i--)
{
    if(i % 2 == 0)
         System.out.println(i + evenodd[0]);
    else
         System.out.println(i + evenodd[1]);
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on SO. Also, given that this is an assignment, it is usually preferred (at least in my opinion) that guidance is given as opposed to a solution which can be simply copy-pasted.

Comment: At no point in your answer you mentioned what the `%` operator is and what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use the `%` operator.

Usage : `x % y` -> This will give you the remainder when y is divided by x.
In your case use y = 2. Hence if the remainder = 0, the number is even else the number will be odd.

I am not giving you the exact code, since this is your assignment. Try it yourself based on the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To find out odd and even number. Follow the logic

> - divide your number by 2 if the reminder is 0 then it is even
> - else it is odd
> - this similar for both positive and negative numbers

to find out reminder use modulo division operator (%). if your_number%2=0 your_number is even else your_number is odd.

Sample code:

```
for(int i=1;i<100;i++){
    if(i%2==0){//for positive number
        System.out.println(i+ " is Even Number");
    }else{
        System.out.println(i+ " is Odd Number");
    }
    if((-1)*i%2==0){//for negative number
        System.out.println((-1)*i+" is Even Number");
    }else{
        System.out.println((-1)*i+" is Odd Number");
    }
}
```